# How to modify the survey-react npm library to change the default color?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am very new to Reactjs and doing some work on it. Now I have used `survey-react` in one place in my code. Now I want to change the default color of `survey-react` to blue, but I am unable to do that. I have used the code like this:

```
import * as Survey from "survey-react"; 
import "survey-react/survey.css";  

...  

<Survey.Survey
    onAfterRenderQuestion={this.onAfterRenderQuestion}
    model={model}
    onComplete={this.onComplete} />
```

Now I want add a prop to make the color to `#1A8FE6`. I have also looked at the JavaScript files for that. Here is that link for that [page](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=custom-theme&platform=Reactjs&theme=modern#content-js).

I want to change `defaultThemeColors["$main-color"] = "#7ff07f";` to
`defaultThemeColors["$main-color"] = "#1A8FE6";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all there in the [documentation](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=custom-theme&platform=Reactjs&theme=modern#content-js). In your file, do this:

```
// Assign Variable
let defaultThemeColors = Survey
    .StylesManager
    .ThemeColors["default"];

// Change the main color
defaultThemeColors["$main-color"] = "#1A8FE6";

// Apply your changes
Survey.StylesManager.applyTheme();
```